# Como adicionar notificação de troca de senha no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Por questões de segurança, em uma das aplicações que estou construindo, sempre que a senha do usuário for alterada este deve ser notificado. Para atender a este objetivo sobrescrevi o método `resetPassword` da classe `ResetsPasswords` em meu `ResetPasswordController` conforme abaixo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

//...

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    //...

    /**
     * Sobrescreve o método padrão para que seja enviada uma notificação de alteração de senha
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        $user->notify(new AlteracaoSenha());
    }
}
```

Conforme pode ser observado, tive que reescrever todo o método para adicionar somente uma linha. Seria possível fazer algo menos volta ao mundo? Tal como:

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    parent::resetPassword($user, $password);

    $user->notify(new AlteracaoSenha());
}
```

Compreendo que este exemplo ai não funciona, este foi citado somente como exemplo do que quero fazer.

*Obs: utilizo Laravel 5.6*

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa sobrescrever o método para isso pois o próprio framework dispara o evento na linha `event(new PasswordReset($user));`.

Sendo assim, o que precisa fazer é criar um [listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#registering-events-and-listeners) para o evento disparado.

Na classe `EventServiceProvider` você registra um listener, por exemplo:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset' => [
        'App\Listeners\AlteracaoSenhaNoty',
    ],
];
```

Depois execute o comando `php artisan event:generate` para gerar a classe `AlteradaSenha`, use então o código a seguir como exemplo:

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;

class AlteracaoSenhaNoty
{

    public function handle(PasswordReset $event)
    {
        $event->user->notify(new AlteracaoSenha());
    }
}
```